# the if statement with % is not working in Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to edit the errors in JavaScript code for a website. I failed to edit an if statement, I tried many solutions and none of them worked.

I tried to remove the % but it is still not working.

```
<script language="javascript">
<% if (flag) then % >
alert('Record Deleted successfully')
<% end if  %>
```

the if and the % signs are underlined. I want to fix these errors but I'm stuck

Comment: That isn't JavaScript.

Comment: Seems like a template engine

Comment: The `alert('...')` part is JavaScript, but the `<% if (flag) then %>` and `<% end if %>` are not. As @QuentinVeron says, those parts look like they're some templating engine.

Comment: what is the 'then' for. Maybee remove that, and it will work? The 'then' seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't Javascript. The if in javascript : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/if...else. Why are you writing "<% %>" ? Are you using a template engine like Twig or anything else of this type ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is a template engine, to go in if statement and make debugging you should write in this way

```
<% if(condition) { %>
//your code
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to output that code, if something withing PHP/templating engine is true, in twig it would look like this:

file.twig

```
{% if variable %}
echo 'hello world';
{% endif %}
```